# Message Text Location of $_SESSION['msg']

Tags: php, html, session

I have Bought one php template from codecanyon. Its working fine but there `$_SESSION` message used to display alert text. I am unable to find where is text for display that text is written. Its used in file like this

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                    <?php echo $client_lang[$_SESSION['msg']] ; ?></a> </div>
                <?php unset($_SESSION['msg']);}?>   
              </div>
```

as well after in query written like this

```
$_SESSION['msg']="11";
```

Its display that " `Data Updated` ".  I want change that text but no any CSS file contains that text. Where should I make changes ?

Thanks.

Comment: 11 is just a code. It gets its text from an array called `$client_lang`. So you have to search where that array is set. Maybe it's a file that's loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Notepad++ text editor, you can use Find in Files from search menu. set your project root folder path and your query for searching. Notepad++ will search content of files for you.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: this same feature is also available in sublime text editor, dreamviewer.